# Reactjs: How to create a function with args inside a component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

In React, sometimes components have a function inside it for when an item is `active` or `pressed` like the Pressable below. How can you recreate this pattern where the `pressed` variable is available inside an object in the args of a function?

```js
<Pressable onPress={ () => null }>
  { ( {pressed} ) => (
    <Text>{pressed ? "Pressed!" : "Press Me"}</Text>
  )
</Pressable>
```

My attempt that doesn't work

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Component = ({ children }) => {
  // Not sure how active should be passed down to children
  // via a useContext maybe? Is that the only way?
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(true);

  return <View>{children}</View>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Component>
        {({active}) => (
          <Text>
            {active ? "Active" : "Not active"}
          </Text>
        )}
      </Component>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass named function expression as a child to the component

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

const Component = ({ children }) => {

  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(true);

  return <View>{children(active)}</View> ;
};

export default function App() {
  const demo = (active) => (
    <Text>
      {active ? "Active" : "Not active"}
    </Text>
  );
  return (
    <View>
      <Component>
        {demo}
      </Component>
    </View>
  );
}
```